# how to sort a stack with recursion?

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void sortStack (stack <int>& s){

    int tempVal;
    int topElement;

    if (s.size()<2){
    return;
    }

    else{
        topElement=s.top();
        s.pop();


        if(topElement < s.top()){
            s.push(topElement);
            return;
            } 

        else {
            tempVal=s.top();
            s.top()= topElement;
            topElement=tempVal;
            sortStack (s); 
            s.push(topElement);
            }  
    }  
}


int main (int argc, char * argv[]){

    try {    
        ifstream inFS;
        int fileNumbers;
        stack <int> s;


        if(argc < 2){
           throw runtime_error ("an error occured: no input file name given");
        }

        inFS.open (argv[1]);
        string fileName = argv[1];

        if (!inFS.is_open()){
            throw runtime_error ("an error occured: could not open input file " + fileName);
        }

        while (inFS >> fileNumbers){
            s.push(fileNumbers); 
            sortStack(s);   
        }

        for (int i=0; i<=s.size(); i++){
          cout << s.top() << " ";  
          s.pop();

        }  

        inFS.close();
    }

    catch (runtime_error & excpt){
        cout << excpt.what() << endl;
    }


return 0;    
}
```

I want to sort numbers from a file in a stack. It has to be a stack and it has to be done with recursion. The numbers in the file are: 4 8 10 3 6 5. It works very well except for the last 2 elements. Thus my output is : 3 4 5 6. It does not sort 8 and 10 as well. Id I do s.size+4 in the for loop it works, but then it doesnot work if I have just one number in the file. Why is that happening???

Comment: Do you have any specific reasons for using stack? Stack is a LIFO structure. Priority queues fit better for this task.

Comment: What do you expect 's.top()=topElement' to do? You assign the return value of s.top() to an uninitialized variable. Even if you fix this I don't see any condition to stop it recursing, si it will run out of stack.

Comment: It may have been deleted, but this exact question was posted yesterday. I don't know if it's the same user or just a classmate. (If classmate, this is a terrible assignment) I can't find a close enough question to flag as duplicate, however.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-a-stack-using-recursion/ might help

Comment: Please separate the code and the prose parts of your question, use the prose parts only once and format all of the code parts. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the loop that generates the output:

```
for (int i=0; i<=s.size(); i++) {
    cout << s.top() << " ";  
    s.pop();
}
```

Every time you execute `s.pop()`, the value returned by `s.size()` will be one less. So this means your loop condition will not check against the *original* size of the stack. And so you'll exit the loop sooner than expected.

It would work correctly if you would read `s.size()` just once, for instance by *starting* with that value:

```
for (int i=s.size(); i > 0; i--) {
    cout << s.top() << " ";  
    s.pop();
}
```

But you could just use a `while` loop:

```
while (s.size() > 0) {
    cout << s.top() << " ";  
    s.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Idea**

- Recursion can be considered as looping with a stack (the call stack).
- Every call, if we take 2 elements at the top of the stack and push back the smaller one. If we continuously call until the stack is empty, the smallest element is the thing left at the last call. So, we can use bubble sort in this scenario.

**Pseudo code**

```
function actual_sort(stack) {
    for (let i=0; i<stack.length; i++)
        sort(stack);
}
function sort(stack) {
    if (stack.length < 2)
        return;
    let [a, b] = stack.pop(2);
    stack.push(min(a, b));
    sort(stack);
    stack.push(max(a, b));
}
```

**Time complexity**

- run steps: n^2
- optimized run steps: n^2 / 2 ( if we limit the depth of stack in each call from `actual_sort`
- time complexity: O(n^2)